# How to get remainder when $33^{111}$ is divided by $111$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How to get the remainder when $33^{111}$ is divided by $111$?

I tried Chinese Remainder Theorem, but that is not working.
Probably due to $(33,111) \neq 1$, right?

Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** It looks like you're misapplying the CRT (Chinese Remainder Theorem, I assume).  Note that $111 = 3 \times 37$.  It follows that if we know the value of $33^{111}$ modulo $3$ and we know the value of $33^{111}$ modulo $37$, then we can find the value of $33^{111}$ modulo $111$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$111=3\times37$ is square-free, and the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) of $111$ is $36$, so $a^{37}\equiv a\bmod111$

Answer (score 0):

You might start with $11$.  $11^2 = 121 \equiv 10 \pmod{111}$ so $11^3 \equiv 10\cdot 11 \equiv -1 \pmod{111}.$

So you have $11^{111} \equiv (11^3)^{37} \equiv (-1)^{37} \equiv -1 \pmod {111}.$

Next, by Fermat's Little Theorem, you have 
$3^{37} \equiv 3 \pmod{37}$, so $3^{111} \equiv
3^3 \equiv 27 \pmod{37}$.  Also $3^{111} \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$ and since $27$ is a multiple of $3$, by CRT, $3^{111} \equiv 27 \pmod{111}.$

Then you have $33^{111} \equiv 3^{111}11^{111} \equiv 27\cdot(-1) \equiv 84 \pmod{111}.$